# There is a problem in pipelines file as it is not fetching the book name. instead saving one random image with None.jpg for each crawl

Tags: python, scrapy, filenames

items.py file. as i was aware of the image_urls and images field. It didn't create any problem.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.loader.processors import TakeFirst

class BooksToScrapeItem(scrapy.Item):
    image_urls = scrapy.Field()
    images = scrapy.Field()
    book_name = scrapy.Field(
        output_processor = TakeFirst()
    )
```

pipelines.py file. I think there must be a problem in the get_media_request method as it is not fetching the book_name from items file

```
from scrapy.pipelines.images import ImagesPipeline
from scrapy import Request


class BooksToScrapeImagePipeline(ImagesPipeline):

    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        return [Request(x,meta={'bookname': item.get('book_name')}) for x in item.get(self.images_urls_field, [])] #i think that the problem is in this line

    def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None):

        return 'full/%s.jpg' % (request.meta['bookname'])
```

spider file which I user for scraping.It worked when i didnt customized the pipeline file.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from books_to_scrape.items import BooksToScrapeItem

class ImgscrapeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'imgscrape'
    allowed_domains = ['books.toscrape.com']
    start_urls = ['http://books.toscrape.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        for article in response.xpath("//article[@class='product_pod']"):
            loader = ItemLoader(item=BooksToScrapeItem(),selector=article)
            relative_url = article.xpath(".//div/a/img[@class='thumbnail']/@src").extract_first()
            abs_url = response.urljoin(relative_url)
            loader.add_value('image_urls',abs_url)
            loader.add_xpath('book_name',".//article[@class='product_pod']/h3/a/text()") 
            yield loader.load_item()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in relative xpath

```
loader.add_xpath('book_name', ".//article[@class='product_pod']/h3/a/text()")
```

Loader uses `xpath("//article[@class='product_pod']")` as selector

```
   for article in response.xpath("//article[@class='product_pod']"):
        loader = ItemLoader(item=BooksToScrapeItem(), selector=article)
```

so all relative xpaths are relative to `"//article[@class='product_pod']"` and they don't need `"//article[@class='product_pod']"` in xpath.

Using relative xpath `".//article[@class='product_pod']/h3/a/text()"` it couldn't find title so `book_name` was empty for all items and for all items it used `None` as title - and it used the same name `None.jpg` for all images.

---

It has to be

```
loader.add_xpath('book_name', ".//h3/a/text()")  # title with `...`
```

---

**BTW:** `text()` doesn't have full title but with `...`. To get full title you has to get attribute `title=`

```
loader.add_xpath('book_name', ".//h3/a/@title")  # full title
```

---

I created version with all code in one file to run it without creating project.

Everyone can copy it to single file and run to test it.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.loader.processors import TakeFirst

class BooksToScrapeItem(scrapy.Item):
    image_urls = scrapy.Field()
    images = scrapy.Field()
    book_name = scrapy.Field(
        output_processor = TakeFirst()
    )

from scrapy import Request
from scrapy.pipelines.images import ImagesPipeline

class BooksToScrapeImagePipeline(ImagesPipeline):

    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        return [Request(x, meta={'bookname': item.get('book_name')}) for x in item.get(self.images_urls_field, [])] #i think that the problem is in this line

    def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None):
        return 'full/%s.jpg' % request.meta['bookname']

from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader

class ImgscrapeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'imgscrape'
    allowed_domains = ['books.toscrape.com']
    start_urls = ['http://books.toscrape.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        for article in response.xpath("//article[@class='product_pod']"):

            loader = ItemLoader(item=BooksToScrapeItem(),selector=article)

            relative_url = article.xpath(".//div/a/img[@class='thumbnail']/@src").extract_first()
            abs_url = response.urljoin(relative_url)

            loader.add_value('image_urls', abs_url)
            #loader.add_xpath('book_name',".//article[@class='product_pod']/h3/a/text()")  # wrong relative xpath 
            #loader.add_xpath('book_name', ".//h3/a/text()")  # only partial title
            loader.add_xpath('book_name', ".//h3/a/@title")  # full title

            yield loader.load_item() 

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

c = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',

    # save in file CSV, JSON or XML
    'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',     # csv, json, xml
    'FEED_URI': 'output.csv', #

    # download images to `IMAGES_STORE/full` (standard folder) and convert to JPG (even if it is already JPG)
    # it needs `yield {'image_urls': [url]}` in `parse()` and both ITEM_PIPELINES and IMAGES_STORE to work

    'ITEM_PIPELINES': {'__main__.BooksToScrapeImagePipeline': 1},            # used Pipeline create in current file (needs __main___)
    'IMAGES_STORE': '.',                   # this folder has to exist before downloading

})
c.crawl(ImgscrapeSpider)
c.start()
```